# ArcGIS or FME - Line feature to linestring or multistring

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form

There are Line feature classes as ShapeFile. The aim is to convert the data set to a CSV using linestring or multilinestring.

Is there a way in ArcGIS or FME?

Comment: Would the geometry be then expressed as WKT or what?

Answer (score 2):

In FME you could use the CoordinateConcatenator transformer. It extracts a list of coordinates and puts them in a comma-separated attribute.

Then you write the attribute out with a Textline writer (it doesn't need to be a CSV writer since you've already got comma-delimited coordinates).

If each line feature has a different number of coordinates then you'll end up with variable length records in the CSV, which may be difficult to read back (depends on where you want to use it).

Here's a [workspace template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vayauq4d2jep40z/CoordConcatDemo.fmwt?dl=1) with a demo:

[image]

Note that I'm using a comma and pipe delimiter, to get x1,y1|x2,y2|x3,y3|x4,etc - but you can use commas all the way if you like.

The result...

```
492416.70013860404,5458952.3584069395|492415.717140069,5458918.3682569498
492406.52828684403,5458597.1220036503|492403.83437528502,5458504.2038255101
492412.265165383,5458801.5987488898|492411.01118068001,5458751.8185354304
492415.717140069,5458918.3682569498|492414.14814729104,5458863.2700158097
492407.87624202698,5458643.5600926699|492406.52828684403,5458597.1220036503
492411.01118068001,5458751.8185354304|492409.270210488,5458691.0002775202
```

Answer (score 0):

[GeometryExtractor](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/geometryextractor.htm) was the transformer I was looking for. By defining the *Geometry Encoding* to *OGC Well Known Text*, the output is *LineString* or *MultilineString*. If [Deaggregator](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/deaggregator.htm) is placed before, the output is *LineString* only.

[image]